# How to paginate a list of images in PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I have a list of images which I want to display in a page.
I want to **paginate** the list of images, so I can have 10 images per page. can you help me to do that?

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? I think it's fair to say that someone here can definitely *help* you with this, it's probably unreasonable to expect them to do *all* the work *for* you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is pagination. There are many tutorials available on the web, for example [this one](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination) looks good.